How to build `CheckMetadataHash` extension in tests?
After thoroughly following the guide to enable the metadata hash and looking through the Polkadot SDK, I unfortunately still fail to verify extrinsics in my integration tests which have CheckMetadataHash enabled via frame_metadata_hash_extension::CheckMetadataHash::<T>::new(true) in the signed extra.
The tests use my real runtime for which the metadata hash check is enabled. Based on the documentation of the build.rs, I need both std as well as metadata-hash enabled for my integration tests. Whereas the former is enabled per default, the second one produces the following SDK error:
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `metadata_ir` in `__private`
   --> /Users/xyz/.cargo/git/checkouts/polkadot-sdk-cff69157b985ed76/c00ca35/substrate/primitives/api/src/lib.rs:797:1
    |
797 | / decl_runtime_apis! {
798 | |     /// The `Core` runtime api that every Substrate runtime needs to implement.
799 | |     #[core_trait]
800 | |     #[api_version(4)]
...   |
827 | |     }
828 | | }
    | |_^ could not find `metadata_ir` in `__private`

My integration tests are all within its own crate integration-tests. I tried a lot with enabling/requiring certain features in the integrationbut did not surpass this error. For example
[features]
default = [
  "my-runtime/metadata-hash",
  "sp-api/frame-metadata"
]


I am sure this can be fixed with using the proper features but I have tried all I could think of at this point. My Polkadot SDK version is v1.7.2. My build.rs and toml of the runtime are following the guide mentioned above.
